# Llamar función dentro de otra función desde fuera en javascript

Tags: javascript

Se podrá llamar a la función `ale()` que esta dentro de otra función.

Por ejemplo:

```
function prueba(){
    function ale(){
        alert('alerta!!');
    }
}
```

Y luego llamarla

```
ale();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En tu ejemplo, lo que puedes hacer es:

```js
function prueba() {
  function ale() {
    alert('alerta!!');
  }
  return ale; //<- añadir un return
}

prueba()(); //hace el alert
prueba();   //no hace nada
```

Esto se llama `currying`.

Como ejemplo más práctico, puedes sumar:

```js
function a(x) {    
  function b(y) { 
    return x + y; 
  }
  return b;       
}
console.log(a(3)(4)); //7

var sumar4 =  a(4); //la variable sumar4 ahora es una funcion
console.log( sumar4(5)); //sumar4 ya le pasamos el 4 antes, ahora suma 5 = 9
```

---

**UPDATE:** (por el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68206/llamar-funci%c3%b3n-dentro-de-otra-funci%c3%b3n-desde-fuera-en-javascript/68209#comment124705_68209) del OP)

Para más de una función puedes hacer uso de la Reflexión.

A `prueba` le pasas la función que quieres llamar, en `string`.

```js
function prueba(fun) {
  var funciones = {};
  funciones.ale1 = function() {
    alert('1');
  };

  funciones.ale2 = function() {
    alert('2');
  };

  //llamada usando reflexion donde fun es el string del nombre del metodo
  return funciones[fun](); 
}

prueba("ale2"); //hace el alert 2
```

Comment: lois6b gracias por tu respuesta. Que pasa si dentro de la `función prueba()` tengo mas de 1 funcion, por ejemplo tener `ale1()`, `ale2()` y `ale3()`. Se pueden diferenciar?

Comment: @DanielCarrillo te la he editado para que lo veas