# ¿Puedo acceder a una función dentro de otra en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguente función

```
function ejemplo() {
    inside = function inside(){
        return 7
    };

    return 5+3;
}
```

¿Podría acceder de alguna forma a la variable inside y ejecutar la función que contiene? Sin tocar la función ejemplo

Comment: *Posible duplicado:* [Llamar función dentro de otra función desde fuera en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/68206/15855)

Comment: sí puedes, pero tienes que ejecutar primero ejemplo

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacer...

```js
    function ejemplo() {
      inside = function indise() { return 7; };
      return 5 + 3;
    }
    
    console.log(ejemplo())
    console.log(inside())
```

El porqué puedes hacer eso es porque `inside` no tiene tipo y en javascript es como si fuera una variable global.

En cambio si haces...

```js
    function ejemplo() {
      let inside = function indise() { return 7; };
      return 5 + 3;
    }
    
    console.log(ejemplo())
    console.log(inside())
```

No podrás acceder a `inside` ya que `let` hace que esté definido dentro del ambito de la función ejemplo. Al igual que si `inside` fuera de tipo `const` o `var`.

Comment: En realidad el porque lo puede hacer es porque no ha indicado el tipo de variable. Como resultado se registra como una variable global. Si indicara `var inside` dentro de la función, tampoco funcionaria, porque se definir dentro (y solo) del `scope` de la función `ejemplo`.

Comment: pregunta: el ejemplo 1 seria una mala practica? porque me viene de perlas declararla de esa manera